# Google Charts not displaying names on yaxis

Tags: google-visualization, ng2-google-chart

I'm having a mare trying to get names to appear alongside data on a google bar chart.  It should be simple!!  Looking at the examples I should not have to add any options at all, they should appear by default but they dont.  Even when I copy/paste the examples from

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

They render *without* the names against the rows.  Can anyone take a guess as to why that might be?

If I position the vAxis.textposition as 'in' then they DO appear in the bars, but when I put them to 'out' they dont.  I've configured the text colour to be black in case they're writing in white, but they still will NOT appear.

Any help or ideas gratefully received

Comment: this happens when the chart's container is hidden when drawn and shown later

Comment: @WhiteHat That isn't the problem.  Looking at the page content and comparing it with the google example, all the <g> entries for the bar names are just missing.  I have absolutely no idea whats going on

Answer (score 0):

This was because I had a  style that was being applied within the generated chart HTML.  Even though the rest of the content looked fine, the sizing meant the labels were not generated